# Remove movieClips using array list?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I've a array of list and created image place holder with the array objects name (Example: myArray[a,b]) and loaded images from there, having array list as folder name.
And finally created a movieClip to load on them and display in stage.

Now I want to remove them calling the same array list.

Need help here...

My code below:

```
for (var l: int = 0; l < ListArray.length; l++) {

    var BookName: MovieClip = new bookThumb();

    trace("\n[" + l + "]: " + ListArray[l]);
    ImageFoldername = ListArray[l];
    var bookImagePath: String = "file://" + File.userDirectory.nativePath.toString() + "/Books/" + ImageFoldername + "/Images/Icon.png";
    trace(bookImagePath);

    var ImagePlacer: Loader = new Loader;
    var ImageURL: URLRequest = new URLRequest(bookImagePath);

    ImagePlacer.load(ImageURL);


    BookName.addChild(ImagePlacer);
    BookName.name = ImageFoldername

    addChild(BookName)

    BookName.x = FirstBook_x;
    BookName.y = FirstBook_y;
    BookName.buttonMode = true;
    BookName.mouseChildren = false;
    BookName.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, IconSelected);
    BookName.alpha = .8
    BookName.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, IconMouseOver);
    BookName.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, IconMouseOut);

    FirstBook_x = FirstBook_x + 250;

}
```

Comment: hello, i do not have flash develop so cannot test this,

I know that adobe has a method called Splice, where it removes an object from an array at position index. 

With this you can use myArrayOfMovieclips.splice(2); 

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000752.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you assign the `ImageFoldername` to each `MovieClip`'s `name` property, you can use `getChildByName` to find them and remove them:

**(Note: convention in AS3 is to use `UpperCamelCase` for classes, and `lowerCamelCase` for variables and functions. I've written the code below following this convention. )**

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < listArray.length; i++) {
    var imageFolderName:String = listArray[i];
    var bookThumb:BookThumb = getChildByName(imageFolderName) as BookThumb;
    if (bookThumb) {
        removeChild(bookThumb);
    }
}
```

---

Another way you can handle it is to add each book thumb into a list:

```
var bookThumbs:Array = [];
for (var i:int = 0; i < listArray.length; i++) {
    var bookThumb:Bookthumb = new BookThumb();
    bookThumbs.push(bookThumb);
    // ...
}
```

Then to remove them all:

```
for each (var bookThumb:BookThumb in bookThumbs) {
    removeChild(bookThumb);
}
bookThumbs.length = 0;
```

---

But probably the *easiest* way to remove them all would be to simply put them all in a single container and later use `removeChildren()` to remove them all:

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(container);
for (var i:int = 0; i < listArray.length; i++) {
    var bookThumb:Bookthumb = new BookThumb();
    container.push(bookThumb);
    // ...
}

// when you want to remove them all:
container.removeChildren();
```